# Email to Case Query

Tags: trigger, email, process-builder, visual-workflow, email2case

I need to do some processing after case gets created through Email to case.
What are possible ways to do processing on case created through Email to case ?

1.After insert trigger
2.Process Builder
3.Flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use process builder to write one process on Email Message object

[image]

and invoke your apex by getting EmailMessage.CaseId

[image]

Comment: Since a new case is being inserted by Email to case, will it be possible to have an after insert trigger on case ?

Comment: if you are implementing this scenario you have caseId which you can use to update case inside apex